# Batch to open & restart Explorer.exe & then restore all the windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, search, windows-10, explorer

For now I have this batch file, which close explorer.exe, wait one second and then open it again (it does its job):

```
@echo off 
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
timeout /t 1 >nul
start explorer.exe
```

Is there a way to restore all the windows (directories) which the above batch has closed for me?
I thought of export all the locations before closing explorer in a .txt file, and then open it again from the same batch file but I haven't tested yet. I'm open to any suggestion.

**Additional information:**

I'm trying to set up a batch for final user (non-"expert" user), so I'd like to make it a "double click" batch which will close explorer and then restore it at its previous state.

The "source" problem of this post is "Windows 10 explorer's search doesn't work":
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-explorer-search-not-working-in-windows-10/3c70ea75-79a8-4f3b-b10a-86be1f22931c
(Windows future version will probably solves this issue, so I just hope to learn something from it)

Comment: I thought that the search box issue was fixed via patch/hotfix/update! Either way, your issue is not one with your code, and is two questions, (not one). The first is looking for opinion, which is off topic anyhow, the second is looking for comment on your thought process and alternatives. Obviously you cannot restore all the windows etc, unless immediately prior to issuing your command, you've backed them all up somehow. If you have an issue with restoring your backed up windows etc. please edit your question to include the backup and restore code, otherwise, please delete your question.

Comment: For your second question may be we can find a solution if we elaborate it more like this vbscript does [List of all dirs in Windows Explorer that are open](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=10319#p10319)

Comment: @Compo I edited my question to be more coherent and concice. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this vbscript [List of all dirs in Windows Explorer that are open](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=10319#p10319) that can be used with a batch script like that :

```bat
@echo off
Title Kill and restart Explorer.exe and restore all the windows by Hackoo 2020
Color 0A
Set "VBSFILE=%~dpn0.vbs"
> "%VBSFILE%" (
    echo Wscript.Echo Opened_Folders
    echo Function Opened_Folders
    echo    Dim objShellApp,wFolder,Open_Folder,F
    echo    Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"^)
    echo    For Each wFolder In objShellApp.Windows
    echo        Open_Folder = wFolder.document.Folder.Self.Path
    echo        F = F ^& Open_Folder ^& vbcrlf
    echo    Next
    echo    Opened_Folders = F
    echo End Function
)
REM  Populate the array with existent and opened folders
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /a Count=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Cscript //NoLogo "%VBSFILE%"') do (
    Set /a Count+=1
    Set "Folder[!Count!]=%%a"
)
Taskkill /f /IM "explorer.exe"
Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Start Explorer.exe
rem Restore all folders before killing explorer process
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do Explorer "!Folder[%%i]!"
pause & exit
```

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. It works as I expected. As @Compo suggested, I will also edit this the question to be more coherent with this answer.